# Django is giving preference to <something> rather than the admin/and login/ urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls

my app urls.py is:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import (handler400, handler403, handler404, 
handler500)

app_name = "bca"

handler404 = 'my_app.views.handler404'

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name='index'),
    path("login/", views.login_request, name='login'),
    path("register/", views.register, name='register'),
    path("logout/", views.logout_request, name='logout'),
    path("<match>", views.match, name='match'),# this is being preferred first...
]
```

when ever i try admin/ in url it gives a value error

[image: Value error:]

What should I do?

Comment: well you're missing the default admin URL which Django puts there for you when you start a new project. Perhaps you don't want to use the default Django admin site? That's not clear (and absolutely fine if you don't want to) - but either way it looks like there is a problem with your `match` view, so we'd need to see that

Comment: oh I just noticed you said this was your app urls.py. Do you have a project level one? What is your `ROOT_URLCONF` setting pointing to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL patterns are for `/admin/`, `/login/` and so on (all with a trailing slash). The error shows you are going to `/admin` (without a trailing slash). If you add the slash, you should see the Django admin.

The default behaviour in Django is to redirect `/admin` (without a trailing slash) to `/admin/`. However, when you add a catch-all pattern like `path("<match>", ...)`, this behaviour stops working. Therefore you should think carefully about whether you really want a catch-all pattern. An alternative would be to display the content from the `match` view on your 404 page.